# Alertmanager is not sending resolved notification for single service

Tags: prometheus

I have setup prometheus and alertmanager for kubernetes cluster.

When any service is down, alertmanager sends "firing" notification to respective channel but does not send notification when that alert resolves.

This happens only for single service, if there are multiple services(in firing/resolved state) then it sends notifications in one mail as expected.

Alertmanager config is

```
route:
  group_by: []
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  receiver: alert-team

receivers:
- name: 'alert-team'
  email_configs:
   - to: 'xyz@xyz.com'
  slack_configs:
  - channel: '#alerts'
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set '*[send_resolved](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#email_config)*' field in '*email_configs*' config to **true**